# Jhipster : what is the meaning of "Unify blueprints configurations"?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I am trying to upgrade my app.
When I type this cmd: `npx jhipster upgrade`.
I have this question:

> ? Unify blueprints configurations? (Y/n)

so I don't know how to answer it.
What does it mean to unify blueprints configurations?

Comment: JHipster issue [#10663](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10663)